# Return key and value in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

How would I go about returning the key and the value to a string or a smaller object:

```
 var whatIsInAName = [{ a: "a1", b: "b1" },{ a: "c1", b: "d1" },{ a: "e1", b: "f1" }];
```

returning something like:
"a:a1"

I know about Object.values and Object.keys. Would it be some combination of this?

Comment: If you don't know the key, and there's no order in objects, how do you get the first one, and does it matter if it's the first one ?

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)?...Though I guess it's not official yet. `Object.entries({foo:"FOO", bar: "BAR"});` This produces... `[["foo","FOO"],["bar","BAR"]]`

Comment: is `whatIsInAName` supposed to be the name of the function you want to return the key and value? Or is it supposed to be the object var name?

Comment: @ camiblanch sorry it is supposed to be the object var name

Answer (score 3):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `Array.prototype.map()`, `JSON.stringify()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/[{}]/g` and replacement string `""`, `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `","`

```js
var arr = [{ a: "a1", b: "b1" },{ a: "c1", b: "d1" },{ a: "e1", b: "f1" }];

var res = arr.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/[{}]/g,""));

console.log(res.join(","))
```